# Is there a function that can restart a WinUI app?

Tags: uwp, winui-3, application-restart, windows-app-sdk

I'm developing a  WinUI3 based app and I need to restart the app to apply some settings. But I can't find a function to do that. I noticed that there is a method--`CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync`. However, it only shut the app down but didn't open the app. Is there an API can restart a WinUI app?

Comment: Are there any specifics in how your app is running? The reason I'm asking - [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.requestrestartasync?view=winrt-22621#remarks) mentions a couple of important things regarding this. For example, "The app must be visible and foreground when it calls this API."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Restart API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/applifecycle/applifecycle-restart):

```cs
// You can pass arguments to the restarted instance.
private void RestartApp(string arguments = "")
{
    // The restart will be executed immediately.
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.AppRestartFailureReason failureReason = 
        Microsoft.Windows.AppLifecycle.AppInstance.Restart(arguments);

    // If the restart fails, handle it here.
    switch (failureReason)
    {
        case AppRestartFailureReason.RestartPending:
            break;
        case AppRestartFailureReason.NotInForeground:
            break;
        case AppRestartFailureReason.InvalidUser:
            break;
        default: //AppRestartFailureReason.Other
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggested Restart API is probably a good place to start.

You should also be able to start a new process like you would start any other .NET process:

```
string path = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(path));
IntPtr intPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
do
{
    intPtr = process.MainWindowHandle;
}
while (intPtr == IntPtr.Zero);

Environment.Exit(0);
```

Comment: This solution sometimes works, but sometimes it only close the app but don't run a new app

Comment: The code starts the process before closing the current one.